why do we need get;set; for custom inner class variables when sending javascript object from LWC to Apex
Why do we need to use get; set; when building wrapper class and passing the object (javascript {} object) from LWC to Apex.
Brief Summary
I have read the stacks from here, but I feel like my question here is not a duplicate and is a valid one, as it primarily focuses on why do we need get;set; when passing in from LWC to Apex? Although, the variables are public?

Problem passing a wrapper class from LWC to Apex
why we use {get; set;} syntax in wrapper class or in controller class

Preface
For example, let's say I have the following Javascript Object:
this.plantDetail = {
        Name: Jasmine,
        Family__c: 'Oleaceae',
        Kingdom__c: 'Plantae',
        Order__c: 'Lamiales',
        index: 0,
        cssclass: 'green-color-plant',
        newPlant: 'yes'
 }

Name and all the properties that end with '__c' are all the fields from Plant (sObject). Now let's say I want to send this same structure to Apex, one way to do it, is to construct
Map<String,Object>

and pass in this object and then I can retrieve the values and typecast them.

Question
But then if let's say I build a class just to store/receive the properties that I added from my LWC (index, cssclass and newPlant) to my Apex.
Then I could do something like this:
public with sharing plantController { //Apex

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void receivePlantInfo(PlantAddedProperties p){
        System.debug(p.index); //null
        System.debug(p.cssclass); //null
        System.debug(p.newPlant); //null
    }
    public class PlantAddedProperties{
        public Integer index;
        public String cssclass;
        public String newPlant;
    }
}


//Javascript
async handleSendPlantDetails(){
    await receivePlantInfo({ p : this.plantDetail});
}

The way to fix this is by adding {get;set;} beside all the variables inside the PlantAddedProperties class. Like below:
    public with sharing plantController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void receivePlantInfo(PlantAddedProperties p){
        System.debug(p.index);    //0
        System.debug(p.cssclass); //'green-color-plant'
        System.debug(p.newPlant); //'yes'
    }
    public class PlantAddedProperties{
        public Integer index {get;set;}
        public String cssclass {get;set;}
        public String newPlant {get;set;}
    }
}

Why do we need to declare this get and set? By right since the variable are public, wouldn't it automatically assign its value when being passed from LWC to Apex?
And even, in Apex, I could even do something like this directly
PlantAddedProperties p = new PlantAddedProperties();
p.index = 2;
p.cssclass = 'new-plant-color'
System.debug(p) //would debug both the variables with the value assigned.

Wouldn't passing value from LWC to Apex do the same? without needing the {get;set;}?
Many thanks in advance for your time and answers! 
Special thanks to Wikipedia, for providing enough informations about Jasmine plant to construct this simplified example.
